Discard all ambiguity from given CFG
Here is given CFG :
CODE→VDECL CODE | FDECL CODE | ϵ
VDECL→vtype id semi | vtype ASSIGN semicolon
ASSIGN→id assign RHS
RHS→EXPR | lit | char | bool
EXPR→EXPR addsub EXPR | EXPR multdiv EXPR
EXPR→lparen EXPR rparen | id | num
FDECL→vtype id lparen ARG rparen lbrace BLOCK RETURN rbrace
ARG→vtype id ARGS | ϵ
ARGS→comma vtype id ARGS | ϵ
BLOCK→STMT BLOCK | ϵ
STMT→VDECL | ASSIGN semicolon
STMT→if lparen COND rparen lbrace BLOCK rbrace ELSE
STMT→while lparen COND rparen lbrace BLOCK rbrace
COND→COND comp COND | bool
ELSE→else lbrace BLOCK rbrace | ϵ
RETURN→return RHS semicolon

What I tried :

Give priority to 'addsub' and 'multdiv' as below :

EXPR -> TERM addsub EXPR | TERM
TERM -> FACTOR multdiv TERM | FACTOR
FACTOR -> lparen EXPR rparen | id | num

fix dangling-else issue with new terminal 'MATCHED', 'UNMATCHED' as below :

STMT -> MATCH | UNMATCH
STMT -> while lparen COND rparen lbrace BLOCK rbrace
UNMATCH -> if lparen COND rparen lbrace BLOCK rbrace
MATCH -> if lparen COND rparen lbrace BLOCK rbrace else lbrace BLOCK rbrace

fix left-recursion of 'COND' as below :

COND -> bool comp COND | bool

After accepting all changes above, and discarding all epsilons, my grammer is :
CODE -> VDECL CODE
CODE -> FDECL CODE
CODE -> VDECL
CODE -> FDECL
VDECL -> vtype id semicolon
VDECL -> vtype ASSIGN semicolon
ASSIGN -> id assign RHS
RHS -> EXPR 
RHS -> lit 
RHS -> char 
RHS -> bool
EXPR -> TERM addsub EXPR
EXPR -> TERM
TERM -> FACTOR multdiv TERM
TERM -> FACTOR
FACTOR -> lparen EXPR rparen
FACTOR -> id
FACTOR -> num
FDECL -> vtype id lparen ARG rparen lbrace BLOCK RETURN rbrace
FDECL -> vtype id lparen rparen lbrace BLOCK RETURN rbrace
ARG -> vtype id ARGS
ARG -> vtype id
ARGS -> comma vtype id ARGS 
ARGS -> comma vtype id
BLOCK -> STMT BLOCK
BLOCK -> STMT
STMT -> VDECL
STMT -> ASSIGN semicolon
STMT -> MATCH
STMT -> UNMATCH
STMT -> while lparen COND rparen lbrace BLOCK rbrace
UNMATCH -> if lparen COND rparen lbrace BLOCK rbrace
MATCH -> if lparen COND rparen lbrace BLOCK rbrace else lbrace BLOCK rbrace
COND -> bool comp COND
COND -> bool
RETURN -> return RHS semicolon

(The reason why I didn't use ' | ' is, I am trying to implement SLR parser, and I use this website to construct SLR parsing table (GOTO-ACTION table).)
Anyway, The problem is here. I already know that there is simple derivations for 'vtype id semicolon' as below :
CODE
-> VDECL CODE
-> vtype id semicolon CODE
-> vtype id semicolon

But, this website with my grammar can not parse 'vtype id semicolon',
so I guess my grammar is still ambiguous.
So main question is :

The things what I did are legit? If not, how can I modify it?

is there any ambiguity after modifications? how can I eliminate rest?


Thanks for help.

I haven't checked all details, but yes, your general approach is correct.
One thing to bear in mind is that SLR doesn't just require unambiguity but a rather strong degree of determinacity.  The difference: a grammar is unambiguous if you never have ambiguity left after parsing has completed; it is deterministic if you never have ambiguity during parsing, and we have different forms of it because we have different parsing techniques, e.g. SLR, LL(k), LR(k).
There are efficient techniques for parsing arbitrary context-free grammars; why not apply one of those instead of having to rewrite your grammar?
